# How to capture multiple different values for the same variable in a single data layer push event

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have a single data layer push that gives me multiple different values but they are for the same variable (the push event is composed of tabular data). I want GTM to pull all of the values in the single event's data layer but I'm getting an "undefined" value return. How can I push all of the Key Value pairs to GTM at once when the Key (variable) is the same?

[2 different sets of variables that are pushed to GTM's data layer with each set having the same variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3AMA.png)  In the highlight you will see tN with each set producing a different value (one "greetings" and the other "family kinship"). How can you create a single Data Layer Customer Variable in GTM that will return two both Greetings and Family Kinship with the single push event, in this case launch_immerse)?

Comment: show examples..

Comment: Even reading I don't understand.

Comment: Please see examples above, thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two different variables with the same name at the same time in GTM.

GTM will update it's internal state (i.e. the value for the variables that are accessible from within GTM) every time a key with the name "event" is pushed to the datalayer (either via external pushes, or via built-in events such as page view, page load, click etc). It will get only the lastest value for a given key, previous values are overwritten.

So you would have to push a key/value, push an event, use that value in your tags, push the next key/value, the next event, trigger your tags etc.

Workarounds include

- sending you data structures as an array of objects, and parse the array within GTM (so you access your key via myarray[index].mykey, where index is some number between zero and myarray.length-1)
- use a custom tag to parse the actual window.dataLayer variable for previous values for the same key

But with built-in tools alone, you will always get only the latest value for a datalayer key.